# Azure Data Factory importing: many to many relationship

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to import a `.csv` file into a Microsoft SQLServer database using Azure Data Factory. The `.csv` file headers look like this

```
VehicleVIN, VehicleMake, VehicleModel, CustomerName, CustomerAddress
```

I've sinked the `VehicleVIN`, `VehicleMake` and `VehicleModel` into a `VehicleTable`. I've sinked the `CustomerRef`, `CustomerName` and `CustomerAddress` into a `CustomerTable`.

Since this is a many to many relationship between those 2 entities, I need to add a third table named `VehicleCustomerTable` (`Id`, `VehicleId`, `CustomerId`) where I should save the id's of the entities that I've sinked into `VehicleTable` and `CustomerTable`.

The problem is that I have no idea of how to associate them in the same data flow. Do I need another data flow for this one? If a separate data flow is needed, how do I know what customer belongs to what vehicle? I've already built a data flow that sinks the data to the corresponding tables but the problem is the association of these 2 entities.

[image: Azure Data Flow]

Comment: Provide sample data and expected output.

Comment: How you created `CustomerRef` column for **CustomerTable**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the input data.

[image]

Here, I added new column **CustomerRef** using `surrogatekey` since you not given in input.
Use **customerid** if you have in your column.

Next, I have done group by using **Aggregate** component on **VehicleVIN** and **CustomerRef**.
Then for aggregate i just used **tmp** as column and `max(CustomerRef)` as value, later I unselected this column in select component. This done just to avoid error.

Below are the settings.

Under `Groub by`

[image]

Under `Aggregates`
[image]

Next, add `surrogatekey` component for creating **Id** column.

settings:
[image]

Preview:

[image]

Then unselect the **tmp** column using `select` component as below.

[image]

Final data preview you will get.

[image]

At the end sink this data to sql table named ****VehicleCustomerTable****.